# C# Split array into individual variables using syntactic sugar

Tags: c#, matlab, syntactic-sugar

I am working on a project to convert Matlab code to C# and there are numerous methods that have the following syntax:

```
var1 = 0
var2 = 1
var3 = 3

% Do something with vars

[var1, var2, var3] = someFunction();
```

...after which the individual variables are accessed normally with the valid return values.

Python's syntax would allow me to translate this directly to:

```
var1, var2, var3 = someFunction()
```

...where `someFunction` returnes a tuple. Is there any kind of syntactic sugar currently in C# that will allow me to do the same thing close to the same way?

Comment: There is no such thing in C#. The closest you could probably do is out parameters, something like: `someFunction(out var1, out var2, out var3)`. Not sure if that makes a lot of sense in your case though, this is not  a typical practice in C#

Comment: Are the values all related? Perhaps you should create a class or struct to encapsulate them together. It's hard to know the best way forward without having more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet, almost all of the Matlab functions I'm translating return multiple values in this way and none are really related between functions. In each case the programmer is trying to do some related calculations in the same method and return all the results in one whack.

Comment: Sounds like a Tuple would be reasonably appropriate then - or refactor the code to stop doing that :)

Comment: Sounds like you should just have a 3 item array, and you probably don't need variables for each item in that array, just access them by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no magic that would make any similar syntax work.

C# *does* have a tuple class ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), so you could write:

```
var tupleResult = someFunction();
var1 = tupleResult.Item1;
var2 = tupleResult.Item2;
...
```

And of course, if the function returned an array you could assign to the individual elements.

The only thing *close* would be to pass as `out` params:

```
someFunction(out var1, out var2, out var3);
```

But that requires having `someFunction` assign those variables, which *rarely* is semantically correct. Using `out` is *usually* a sign you are on the wrong path (with some notable exceptions, like `TryParse`).

Answer (score 1):

For best practice you shouldn't use tuples in c#, it makes your code be less readable.
Instead, wrap the result in class:

```
public class ValueSet
{
    public ValueSet(string value1, string value2, string value3)
    {
        Value1 = value1;
        Value2 = value2;
        Value3 = value3;
    }

    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if you to make any operations on this three variables you will create a function in this class.

Comment: If you are going to make a class, please make the property names more descriptive than `Value1`, `Value2`, etc. You might as well use the Tuple at that point :). Otherwise, this is good advice.